# Maximum single-precision floating-point format number

Tags: number-formats

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) wikipedia article the maximum single precision is 7f7fffff. Can some explain me why it is (7f7fffff)16 and not (7fffffff)16?

(7f**7**fffff)16 = (0111 1111 **0**111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111)2
(7f**f**fffff)16 = (0111 1111 **1**111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111)2

Answer (score 3):

The second exponent is FF, which signals NaN according to Wikipedia, and so the highest exponent is only FE. This is verified by the following C code snippet:

```
unsigned int i = 0x7FFFFFFF;
float f = *(float*)&i;
```

If you print `f` you get `nan`.